# Running a discord.js node keeps returning ReferenceError: Intents is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am an absolute beginner to making a Discord.js bot. Currently I'm trying to run a tutorial bot for the first time but I keep getting ReferenceError: Intents is not defined for the following source code.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [Discord.Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.login('token here');
```

Here's my full error log:

```
ReferenceError: Intents is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\duyba\source\DiscordBot\main.js:2:47)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using discord.js v14, the method has changed. Now you need to use:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds], partials: [Partials.Channel] });
```

Check the full v13 to v14 guide [here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v14.html#enum-values).

Answer (score 1):

The intent flags are not necesary.
Simply just put them as strings like this:

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [ 'DIRECT_MESSAGES', 'GUILD_MESSAGES' ] });
```

Answer (score -1):

In version 13.1.0 at this date. You must import the flags from the package.

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
```

[As shown here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#enabling-intents)