# Discord Bot - ReferenceError: Intents is not defined

Tags: javascript, json, android-intent, discord, bots

i'm trying to code a simple bot for my server on discord but this error happened:

> ReferenceError: Intents is not defined

My code is really simple:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();

bot.login('TOKENcode');

bot.on("message", (message) =>{
    console.log('hello world!');
})
```

what should i do? i just want to write a message on Discord and make my Visual Studio Code prompt say "hello world!"

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Discord.js documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68719646/running-a-discord-js-node-keeps-returning-referenceerror-intents-is-not-defined) you need to pass `Intents` to you `client` initialization. New Discord rules for bot developers has been set that every bot creator needs to pass intents.

For example, this is a simple construction, copied from the documentation:

```js
// Define Client and Intents
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

// Set flags for your bot
// All flags: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Intents?scrollTo=s-FLAGS
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
    ]
});


client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
});

// Receive messages sent in your server.
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    console.log('Hello World!');
});

client.login('token');
```

`!` Note that Discord.js version 13, requires [Node.js v16](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) to be installed on your machine. Make sure you have installed this by typing `node -v` in your console.